# try block inside while statement

Tags: python, if-statement, exception, while-loop

I'm just starting out with Python 2.7 and I don't understand why something is happening:

In the following code, an embellished version of an example from the python 2.7.2 tutorial, I get an unexpected result:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Oops!  That was not a valid number.  Try again..."
    else:
        print 'Thanks,',x,'is indeed an integer'
    finally:
        print 'all done, bye'
```

When I put in an integer, the code ignores the `else:` statement and cuts straight to `finally:`.  Clearly it's something to do with the `while True:` at the top but why is it happening?

Answer (score 25):

The break statement is pulling out of the loop, so the else statement will never be reached.

Put the break in the else clause instead, like so:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print "Oops!  That was not a valid number.  Try again..."
    else:
        print 'Thanks,',x,'is indeed an integer'
        break

print 'all done, bye'
```

Answer (score 7):

It is probably because of the `break` statement, which leaves the loop. The `break` statement is only reached when there is no exception in the line before.

Answer (score 3):

Not a python guy, but how about this

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
        print 'Thanks,', x, 'is indeed an integer'
    except ValueError:
        print "Oops!  That was not a valid number. Try again..."
    finally:
        print 'all done, bye'
```

Answer (score 0):

i recently faced a question in which no input, for how many test cases .`while` loop and `try-except` are very helpful.

```
while(True):
    try:
        x=(input())
        x1,x2=x.split()
        print(int(x1)+int(x2))
    except:
        break
```