# python / Photoshop foreground color changing

Tags: python-2.7, photoshop

i have very basic knowledge base in python, and i am working on a project to interact with Photoshop. 
i managed to do most what i want expect a last issue
as my program is continuously reading from Photoshop (foreground colour) and writing to Photoshop the same hing. my issue is when the program is busy and not ready to accept data such as when a dialog window is open, python try to send data and fail and stop the application 
i am using python 2.7 and following some of the codes I am using
I guess I need to check the port if it is ready before sending anything

```
psApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")
psApp.foregroundColor = solidcolor   #to send the new data to Photoshop
```

thanks

Comment: Maybe you could send inside a `try/except` block to handle the failed send gracefully...

Comment: many thanks to your answer Brandon ... not sure how to do so .. but definitely  will try.... if you got any sample please do comment it.. thanks again

Comment: It'll look like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11758128/2836621except `x=int...` will become `psApp...`

Comment: Thanks Mark.... my Knowledge in Python is too basic so I treid what you suggest but still cant figure it out. I will put the part of the code that I need it to check the port before based on what you suggest ...

Comment: try:
    psApp = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Photoshop.Application")

    psApp.foregroundColor = solidcolor #applying solidColor array to photoshop foreground color

except ValueError:
    print "BUSY"

else:
    
    print "OK"

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all who tried to help me with this issue... 
I managed to solve it buy using try, except ... also I figured it out that the break was happens to the timer that apply the values not to the protocol itself
many thanks again