# Breaking out of Try Except inside While loop

Tags: python

```py
def marks():
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input("Enter the marks 1 : "))
            y = int(input("Enter the marks 2 : "))
            z = int(input("Enter the marks 3 : "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a integer")
        break
```

I'm a beginner in Python, I can't seem to break out of the loop after I get all the correct values from the inputs. Why is this happening?

Comment: Put the break at the end of `try:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [try block inside while statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758029/try-block-inside-while-statement)

Comment: I've executed your program and it is stopping the loop. But stopping the loop is independent of entering valid or invalid input, that's the bug I personally found

Answer (score 3):

Currently, after 1 iteration of your `while` loop, you break out of it due to the placement of your `break` statement. To fix this, put the `break` statement after all inputs have been taken and they don't throw any errors:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("Enter the marks 1 : "))
        y = int(input("Enter the marks 2 : "))
        z = int(input("Enter the marks 3 : "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a integer")
```

Comment: Alternatively, I like `try/except/else: break`, but I'm kind of a purist about keeping the bare minimum of code inside the `try` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `while True` you can use a condition to evaluate if you've received valid input yet

```
def marks():
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        try:
            x = int(input("Enter the marks 1 : "))
            y = int(input("Enter the marks 2 : "))
            z = int(input("Enter the marks 3 : "))
            valid = True
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a integer")
```

So every time you end up in your exception block you've received invalid input, but if you make it to `value = True` that means your `while` loop condition will be satisfied and the loop will not continue.

Comment: Why use this rather than a `while` loop?

Comment: What do you mean "rather than" it **is** a while loop?

Comment: Some might prefer this for explicitness, but this is strictly equivalent to having a `break` at the end of the `try`.

Comment: I mean a `while True` loop as the OP wanted?

Comment: Because `while True` does not express intent, a loop should have a human-readable termination condition

Comment: @CoryKramer Maybe it's better to fix OP's code so they can learn?

Comment: @Xnero I did fix the OP's code, my answer is what I suggest they change their code to

Comment: @CoryKramer Your answer does not teach them how to use `break` statements, their fundamental error.

Comment: @Xnero Cory's correction could also be seen as a "fundamental" error that the OP made. Part of gaining experience is learning how to frame problems in ways that make the most sense. Cory not only offered a valid solution but as a bonus, gave the OP the useful tip to strive for a human-readable termination condition when crafting the loop.

Comment: Do you mean while loop condition will NOT be satisfied and loop will not continue?

Comment: @AbhijitShirwal In this context, satisfied has a closer meaning to "resolved" -- there is not really a positive or negative connotation implied as sometimes is the case in colloquial English.

Comment: @Justin Dehorty Ok, I personally thought that it should be "while loop condition is not satisfied" and it seems strange to read "while loop condition is satisfied and loop will not continue". But you seem correct here, cheers

Answer (score 0):

There's indent error in your code. The `while` statement should be indented correctly. And to break the loop, change the break statement from the current position to try section. The code will work as follows:

1. try to execute the "try section" normally
2. the moment it gets error, it will jump to except section and while loop will be still going on and it'll again ask for 3 inputs
3. if there's no error it'll simply execute the try section and break the loop

Your code:

```
def marks():
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input("Enter the marks 1 : "))
            y = int(input("Enter the marks 2 : "))
            z = int(input("Enter the marks 3 : "))
            break         #break if all inputs are correct
        except ValueError:       #execute the moment we get error
            print("Please enter a integer")
marks()      #calling function
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a return command. ı dunno why photon expects this but if you change it like this it will stop after one loop.

````
  def marks():
    while True:
      try:
        x = int(input("Enter the marks 1 : "))
        y = int(input("Enter the marks 2 : "))
        z = int(input("Enter the marks 3 : "))
        return None
      except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a integer")```
````